# Start Embedded jetty Server with separate JVM attached to it

Tags: embedded-jetty

Hi have started Embedded Jetty server with in my Java Code, but it attached to the same JVM. Can we start Embedded Jetty Server with a separate JVM attached to it.

Is there any way of doing it. Please let me know.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` ? Command being a script, an invocation to launch java on your Main.class, etc...

I am not sure why you want to do that but if you are attempting to control the JVM running Jetty from the 'outside' then you should look at [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp).

The wrapper provides a Java API that gives you the ability to control the lifecycle of your app. Version 3.2.3 is available under a different license if that matters.

Comment: The java code will spun multiple Jetty Server instances. Some application will run on these instances. If all these instances will  run on same JVM then the memory will be the problem.

I am able to do that through command prompt but I want it from the java code itself.
Command : java -jar start.jar --exec